# ssh command to run remote script exist shell on remote server when switching user

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, sh

When I run a script such as this:

```
ssh -t root@10.10.10.10 '/tmp/somescript.sh'
```

where the script is defined as:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p /data/workday/cred
chown -R myuser:myuser /data
su myuser -  # <------- NOTICE THIS ! ! ! ! 
rpm -Uvp --force --nodeps --prefix /data/place /data/RPMs/myrpm.rpm
```

Notice the above **su** command.

If I comment-out the **su** command, the script runs remotely and then my shell prompt returns to where I came from ( same server where I ran the ssh command above )

But leaving the script as listed above, causes the script to complete successfully but the **shell prompt stays on the remote server**.

How can I prevent that ? Making sure that the issuer of the rpm command is a different user than root just a listed ?

Comment: asking the same question on multiple sites is discouraged: http://serverfault.com/q/569408/30957

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But leaving the script as listed above, causes the script to complete successfully but the shell prompt stays on the remote server.

Not exactly. The script is running up to the `su` command, which spawns a new subshell, and stopping there until you exit the shell. Until you exit that shell, the `rpm` command never runs, and when it does, it runs as root.

If you want to run the `rpm` command as a non-root user, you'd need to do something a little different, like:

```
sudo -u myuser rpm -Uvp ...
```

Answer (score 0):

add 'exit' at the end of your script

Comment: That wouldn't make any difference at all.